# How to find the number of transactions per day or per hour in a SQL 2000 database

Tags: transaction, sql-server-2000

I am trying to find a query that I can run in order to find the number of transactions per day or per hour in a SQL 2000 database. The purpose is to get the number of hits on the database.

I have tried something similar to the query below but this seems to belong to newer versions of SQL Server not SQL server 2000.

```
 DECLARE @ctr bigint
 SELECT @ctr = cntr_value 
 FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
 WHERE counter_name = 'transactions/sec' 
 AND object_name = 'SQLServer:Databases' 
 AND instance_name = 'SomeDBName'
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
 SELECT cntr_value - @ctr 
 FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
 WHERE counter_name = 'transactions/sec' 
 AND object_name = 'SQLServer:Databases' 
 AND instance_name = 'SomeDBName'
```

Comment: Does it need to be a query? Otherwise you could use the transactions/sec performance counter from perfmon. Not sure if you can filter that on database though (i don't have any SQL2k's laying around fortunately

Comment: How about querying sysprocesses like `select count (*) from sysprocesses where spid> 50 and dbid=db_id(N'db_name')` and then dumping record into some table at whatever interval you like

Comment: I have tried that one, I did get the follwoing:                                                                               `Server: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sysprocesses'.`

Comment: Did you ran the command in master database you have to run it in master DB.Or try `select count (*) from master..sysprocesses where spid> 50 and dbid=db_id(N'db_name')` I am rusty with SS 2000 neither I have it to check the syntax

Comment: It did work. If I understand this well spid is the sysprocess ID. when I ran the query `select count (*) from sysprocesses`, I get larger number. is this the number of transaction for the day?

Comment: Generally in SQL Server 2000 SPID <50 is system process not user process so I filtered query with SPID>50. Any SPID greater than 50 is user connecting to SQL Server